# Battery detected, working but not charging

Tags: battery

My Dell laptop runs Ubuntu 14.04 LTS . It's saying that it's charging but it's stuck on 10% . I tried different chargers but it doesn't work . Help?
I have this problem since I started using Ubuntu. Help, please!!

Comment: Have you tried another battery?  You'd get about that (depending on cell count) if the battery had a shorted cell.  Might also try your battery in another compatible computer, if you have access to one -- that would isolate your computer's charging and battery management systems.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a brand new Asus Eee PC Seachell series running 12.04.  At first, I thought it was something wrong with the OS, but, after other problems (including the fall of one very rarely used key), I concluded  that it was just a technical malfunction.  You buy something low-end, it works like low-end. I think you should check on a service first, before assuming that there is a software problem.

Comment: yes I tried my battery in anther  laptop and it worked and it worked when my laptop ran on windows 8